# If we add a constant weight vector with an absolute function, does it still remain convex then?

Tags: regression, optimization, lasso, quantile-regression, convex

We know that absolute functions are convex. Now what if we add a constant weight vector to it, does it still remain convex?
Say the equation is **Absolute loss regression + L1 regularization**, we know that absolute loss regression is a convex function, so does adding L1 regularization preserves its convexity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function is **convex** if it obeys the following inequality, for $\{0<a<1,  a+b=1\}$:

$$f(ax+by)\leq af(x)+bf(y)$$

Restricting the inequality we can define **strict convex** functions as the ones that obey

$$f(ax+by)\lt af(x)+bf(y)$$

If $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2}=|x|$, then by the triangle inequality:

$$f(ax+by)=|ax+by|\leq a|x|+b|y|$$

Thus the absolute value is a convex function (though not strictly convex), as you correctly pointed out.

The addition of convex functions is convex, so a objective like $\mathcal L = |\beta^TX-Y|+\lambda|\beta|$ is a convex function of $\beta$.

Now, onto convex optimization.
In convex optimization, all local minimums are global minima. $\mathcal L$ is convex, so it has a single minimum as well: the global minimum.  Thus it admits an unique optimum value. It does not guarantee uniqueness of the solution $\hat \beta$ however, only strictly convex functions admit a single solution. This means that it is possible for different $\hat \beta$ to achieve the same optimum.

So, the answer is yes, it remains convex.

Comment: Thank you... :)